# How to remove empty array from multidimensial array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1367
            [category_value] => 15
            [isepisode] => 0
            [title] => hello world
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9892
            [category_value] => 
            [isepisode] => 0
            [title] => 
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9895
            [category_value] => 
            [isepisode] => 0
            [title] => Bla Bla
        )
)
```

I want to remove array those `title` is empty.

Here is my code:

```
$res = array_map('array_filter', $data);
print_r(array_filter($res)); exit;
```

Above code only removing those array values are empty. But I want to remove whole array which title is null. My output should be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1367
            [category_value] => 15
            [isepisode] => 0
            [title] => hello world
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9895
            [category_value] => 
            [isepisode] => 0
            [title] => Bla Bla
        )
)
```

**Note:** I have thousands of array. If put foreach this will take time to execute. Is there any easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right `array_filter()` approach:

```
$result = array_filter($arr, function($a){ return $a['title']; });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of callback argument in [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). For example:

```
$result = array_filter($data, function($entry) {
    return ! empty($entry['title']);
});

print_r($result);
```

Better yet, if you check the [user contributed notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#usernotes) section of the docs, you can see:

> If you want a quick way to remove `NULL`, `FALSE` and Empty Strings (""), but leave values of `0` (zero), you can use the standard php function strlen as the callback function:
>
> e.g.:
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> // removes all NULL, FALSE and Empty Strings but leaves 0 (zero) values
> $result = array_filter( $array, 'strlen' );
> ```

Comment: for *user contributed notes* +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with a custom callback function that implements your filtering rule:

```
$res = array_filter
    $data,
    function (array $item) {
        return strlen($item['title']);
    }
);
```

The callback function returns `0` for the items whose `title` is the empty string (or `NULL`). `array_filter()` removes these entries from the provided array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using `foreach()` try something like this:

```
$array = array(array('id'=>1,'title'=>'john'),array('id'=>2,'title'=>''),array('id'=>3,'title'=>'mike'));
foreach($array as $key => $val){
    if($val['title']==''){
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```